# Symfony2 Undefined variable: handleRequest

Tags: php, html, symfony, yaml

I am trying to develop a basic form in Symfony2 and to get the `handleRequests` to work. However I am having the error `undefined variable handleRequest` and cannot seem to solve the problem!

This is my Controller

```
 <?php
namespace James\workBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use James\workBundle\Entity\Task;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {    
        $task = new Task();

        $task->setTask('Write a blog post');
        $task->setDueDate(new \DateTime('tomorrow'));

          $form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
           ->add('task','text')
           ->add('dueDate','date')
           ->add('save','submit')
           ->getForm();

          $form = $handleRequest($request);

         if ($form->isValid())
             {
               exit('form was valid');
               return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('task_new'));
              }

            //  $request = $this->getRequest(

           //if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST'){
               // $form->bindRequest($request);
                 //if ($form->isValid())
                   //{
               //return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('task_success'));
          // }
      // }

        return $this->render('JamesworkBundle:Default:index.html.twig', 
              array(
                'form'=> $form->createView(),
                )); 
    }
}
```

This is my Twig

```
 {% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
  <div class="container">

{{form(form)}}

  </div> 

{% endblock %}
```

this is my Routing

```
task_new:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: JamesworkBundle:Default:new  }

task_success:
     path: /success
     defaults: { _controller: JamesworkBundle:Default:success }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mistyped this line:

```
$form = $handleRequest($request);
```

`handleRequest` is a method of `$form` that handles the `POST` request.

It should be:

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```